# Вопрос про доступность полей и методов объекта synchronized блока

Tags: java, многопоточность, concurrency, synchronized

Сдавал финальный экзамен на intuit.ru. Курс по java, на следующий вопрос про `synchronized`-блок получил, что ответ неверный. Никак не могу понять почему. Может кто подскажет, спасибо.

[image: Вопрос на экзамене Intuit.ru]

В самом курсе черным по белому написано, что и к полям, и к методам объекта, на который вешается lock, можно без проблем обращаться другим потокам. (Ну, видимо, кроме synchronized методов, ибо они пытаются повесить lock на объект, из которого вызываются, а он уже залочен по условиям задачи. Но сути это не меняет, к полям тоже можно обращаться, т.е. вариант 4 не подходит...)

Может что с 2003 года поменялось... (курс старый)

Comment: Может они имеют в виду синхронизацию по монитору как раз этой ссылки на объект? Если да, то 4-ый вариант правдоподобно выглядит

Comment: По тому, как сформулирован вопрос - ответ 3 верный (должно быть да, да). Можете смело писать разработчику курса.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут три варианта: либо вопрос поставлен некорректно, либо ответы сформулированы не совсем ясно (особенно третий, который можно трактовать в сторону правильного), либо в тесте ошибка и правильного варианта ответа нет.

Если один поток начал исполнение `synchronized`-блока, указав ссылку на некий объект, то другой поток сможет обратиться к полю этого объекта и так же сможет обратиться к методу этого объекта (**если метод не синхронизированный**).

Синхронизация по объекту накладывает ограничение на другие блоки синхронизации по этому же объекту и на вызов синхронизированных методов. На доступ к полям и не синхронизированным методам `synchronized`-блок не влияет.

И пример:

```
public class Foo {
    public int mValue = 5;

    public String bar() {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main {
    private static Foo sFoo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        sFoo = new Foo();

        new Thread(() -> f()).start();

        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Second thread: start");
            System.out.println("Member: " + sFoo.mValue);
            System.out.println("Method: " + sFoo.bar());
            System.out.println("Second thread: end");
        }).start();


    }

    private static void f() {
        synchronized (sFoo) {
            try {
                System.out.println("First thread: start");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("First thread: end");
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
First thread: start
Second thread: start
Member: 5
Method: bar
Second thread: end
First thread: end
```